# How to deploy images on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

How can I deploy images to Google App Engine?

My image is in the directory /css/images/error1.png
But on appspot.com: "The requested URL /css/images/error1.png was not found on this server."

What is wrong? 
The upload-log: http://pastebin.com/VAK5hYPC

Answer (score 5):

[Have you mapped the directory as a static directory in your app.yaml file?](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_File_Handlers)

Comment: This is my app.yaml: http://pastebin.com/SVEkTnDC |
Other pictures are working in the same directory. Only error1.png dont work.  My page: http://stclaus-de.appspot.com/

Comment: your app.yaml looks over-complicated, try this instead http://pastebin.com/1tCLYAGC

Answer (score 0):

Try this and type in the url path in your browser to see if the image is found (Might even be a typo somewere)

```
- url: /css
  static_dir: static/css/images
```